# how rails server understand which project to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, server, weblogic

I am new to rails . I have multiple projects in my workspace. When i hit http://localhost:3000/ , I want to know how to distinguish between different projects. Say there are three projects A,B,C in my workspace and I want to run A in my browser. How to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are familiar with `rvm`, and must be using that.
If you want to run a particular project. Go to your project's directory and hit `rails s`.

if you want to run servers of more than one projects at one time, then give the port also to run the server. e.g:

```
rails s -p 3001
rails s -p 3002
```

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal locate in the folder of your project

```
$ cd projects_folder
$ cd project_A
$ rails s
```

You will see this message

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Minimize your terminal and open http://localhost:3000 in your favorite browser.

When you want to change of project maximize your terminal and

> press ctrl+c to stop the process

Locate in other folder

```
$ cd .. 
$ cd project_B
$ rails s
```

I recommend you read [this to learn how to navigate in terminal](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0020.php)